# Tcsh shell script "syntax error unexpected end of file" for if statement

Tags: shell, tcsh

I saw a similar problem in bash but couldn't solve it for my case. 
I'm running a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set mystring=0

if ( "$mystring" == "0" )    
  echo "true"     
elseif    
  echo "wrong"    
endif
```

my output is "line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file". Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working bash version (rather than tcsh), given the first line in your example:

```
#!/bin/bash
mystring="0"
if [ "$mystring" -eq "0" ]; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "wrong"
fi
```

Note that much of the syntax was slightly incorrect for bash, even though the logic all looked correct.  You should also determine if "mystring" is going to be an integer or a string type - here I made the assumption that you're expecting strings, and modified the example accordingly.

Comment: Agree, mix of bash and tcsh. OP, which do you want? Your headline says tcsh. Also any variation of elseif (elif) per the original sample code requires something to test, for example `elif [[ -f ${fileToProcess} ]] ; then ...`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using tcsh then your if syntax is wrong. Use as below

```
if ( "$mystring" == "0" ) then
commands
else
commands
endif
```

you might face the issue even after changing this. it can be resolved by **sourcing your script** instead of just typing its name in the shell. i.e.,

```
$source script.sh
instead of
$script.sh
```